# T-SQL - Compare two tables and display result as Available on Both, table1 only and table2 only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, compare

I have 2 tables and structure is same on both tables.

Table 1:

```
ID  Name    Phone
1   xxx     111
2   yyy     222
```

Table 2:

```
ID  Name    Phone
1   xxx     111
3   zzz     333
```

I need to compare these two tables and display the results (based on ID column- where condition ID) as

```
Available in both tables
Table1 only
Table2 only
```

This should be like this,

```
ID  Name    Phone   Status
----------------------------------------
1   xxx      111    Available in both
2   yyy      222    Available in T1 only
3   zzz      333    Available in T2 only
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work:

```
CREATE TABLE #T1 ( ID INT, Name VARCHAR(10), Phone VARCHAR(10) )
CREATE TABLE #T2 ( ID INT, Name VARCHAR(10), Phone VARCHAR(10) )

INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES ( 1, 'xxx', '111' ), ( 2, 'yyy', '222' )
INSERT INTO #T2 VALUES ( 1, 'xxx', '111' ), ( 3, 'zzz', '333' )

SELECT #T1.ID, #T1.Name, #T1.Phone, 'Available on both' AS Status
FROM #T1 INNER JOIN #T2 ON  #T1.ID = #T2.ID
UNION
SELECT #T1.ID, #T1.Name, #T1.Phone, 'Available on T1 only' AS Status
FROM #T1 LEFT JOIN #T2 ON  #T1.ID = #T2.ID
WHERE #T2.ID IS NULL
UNION
SELECT #T2.ID, #T2.Name, #T2.Phone, 'Available on T2 only' AS Status
FROM #T1 RIGHT JOIN #T2 ON  #T1.ID = #T2.ID
WHERE #T1.ID IS NULL

DROP TABLE #T1
DROP TABLE #T2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
declare @table1 table
(
name varchar(10),
phone varchar(10)
)
declare @table2 table
(
name varchar(10),
phone varchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES('xxx','111')
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES('yyy','222')

INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES('xxx','111')
INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES('zzz','333')

SELECT t1.name, t1.phone, 'Available on both' FROM 
@table1 t1 INNER JOIN @table2 t2 
ON t1.name = t2.name and t1.phone = t2.phone
UNION
SELECT name, phone, 'Available on T1 only' FROM 
@table1 t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM @table2 t2 
WHERE t1.name = t2.name and t1.phone = t2.phone)
UNION
SELECT name, phone, 'Available on T2 only' FROM 
@table2 t2 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM @table1 t1 
WHERE t1.name = t2.name and t1.phone = t2.phone)
```

Answer (score 1):

using HASHBYTES :<kbd>[Demo Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/703091)</kbd> ..you dont need to consume table mutiple times,but only once

```
;with cte
as
(
select id,name,phone,hashbytes('sha1',concat(id,name,phone) )as tb1
from #t1
)
select  isnull(c.id,b.id) as id,
        isnull(c.name,b.name) as name,
        isnull(c.phone,b.phone) as phone,
case when c.tb1 is null then 'exists in second table only'
     when c.tb1 is not null and b.tb1 is not null then 'exists in both'
     when b.tb1 is null then 'exists in first table only'
     end as 'exidts' from cte c
full join
(

select id,name,phone,hashbytes('sha1',concat(id,name,phone) )as tb1
from #t2
) b
on
b.tb1=c.tb1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of **FULL JOIN** and **IS NULL** to check availability from both tables -

```
SELECT ISNULL(t1.id, t2.id) AS Id
       , ISNULL(t1.name, t2.name) AS Name
       , ISNULL(t1.phone, t2.phone) AS Phone
       , CASE
            WHEN t1.id IS NULL THEN 'Available in T2 only'
            WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN 'Available in T1 only'
            ELSE 'Available in both'
        END AS Status
FROM Table1 AS t1
FULL JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON (t2.id = t1.id);
```

As this query uses only one JOIN operation and no sub queries it is very fast.